# My HTML5 button keeps refreshing the browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple button that has a click event binded to its ID.  This button retrieves a value from a slider that is then outputted to a `<span>` nested within a paragraph.  The problem is that when the button is pressed, the page refreshed so I see the value for a split second then it dissapears.  In the real world I will want this to happen when all values are submitted to a server, but for now I just need the page not to refresh when I click my button:

```
// Output to the value of slider one
$("#slider01").on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var sliderValue = $(this).val();
    $("#value").text(sliderVal);
});

// Retrieve the value from slider one
$("#submit").on("click", function(evt) {
    var sliderValue = $('#slider01').val();
    $("#output > p").append(sliderValue);
    //alert("The value of slider 1 is: " + sliderValue);
});
```

Heres my two main functions.

Comment: You can simply change input type to `button` this will prevent the issue :)

Comment: Just wanted to reiterate like @Sergio mentioned before, you should go through your questions and accept and or upvote the answers that were helpful for you, you have 16 questions now with no accepted answers.  People will be less inclined to help you in the future if you don't accept their answers.

Comment: Sorry guys, you help is much appreciated.  I've done the necessary regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your form is being posted when you click the button.  To prevent this from happening add `evt.preventDefault()`

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var sliderValue = $('#slider01').val();
  $("#output > p").append(sliderValue);
  //alert("The value of slider 1 is: " + sliderValue);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What type is the button you're clicking? For a `type="submit"` button, the refresh is what it's supposed to do. You might want to try a simple `type="button"`, at least until you get to the point you really do want the submit to occur.

Comment: The strange thing was that I was initially using a `type="submit"` which as you say is supposed to refresh, then I changed it for a basic button and still the page refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if your button is of type "submit". Return false to prevent the form from continuing with the submit:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(evt) {
    var sliderValue = $('#slider01').val();
    $("#output > p").append(sliderValue);
    //alert("The value of slider 1 is: " + sliderValue);
    return false;
});
```

You will then have to manually call `$('form').submit();` once you are actually ready to submit it.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a better option.  The weird thing is that I did delete `type="submit"` and replaced it with a normal button and still the page was refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

To not reload the page on the button click, use this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  return false;
}
```

Secondly, you can also try to use this in `success`'s function if you're using ajax request by jQuery.

Third, what is the code for that? I am sure there is a form and the `input[type="submit"]` button, which sends the whole page to the server. Remove that and use simple `button`.

Comment: Thanks, as you say the submit button is what I will need when the information needs to be sent to a server.  I did replace it with `<button name="submit1" id="submit">Submit</button>` but still the page refreshed, until I added the necessary code you guys suggested.